# How can I set salt for bcrypt.hashpw?

Tags: python, django, hash, bcrypt

```
    salt = 'yhnqazolr123098765'
    password = bcrypt.hashpw(password,salt)
    repeatpassword = bcrypt.hashpw(repeatpassword,salt)
```

I got error for the second line.

```
ValueError at /register

Invalid salt

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

Invalid salt

Exception Location:     /home/user1/djangoblog/blog/views.py in register, line 70
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/home/user1/djangoblog',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
```

What to do?
I need to set some default salt value rather than random salt every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, as in the example found in the [project page](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-bcrypt/), you need something like this:

```
salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
password = bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt)
repeatpassword = bcrypt.hashpw(repeatpassword,salt)
```

Comment: But if i use these, `password = bcrypt.hashpw(password,bcrypt.gensalt());   passwordrepeat = bcrypt.hashpw(passwordrepeat,bcrypt.gensalt())` the `password` and `passwordrepeat` won't match, so it can't be saved.

Comment: @guru If you need to use the same `salt`, then you can use a variable to save the output from `bcrypt.gensalt`. I've updated my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: But as it's randomly created salt, then when you take/retrieve the password from database table and compare it with the given password to login, then would the salt value be same?

Comment: Of course, you'll need to store the salt in the database. For example, in django you'll see that what is stored in the password field is something like: `'[algo]$[salt]$[hexdigest]'`

Comment: Normally, the salt value is not added in database. Can i use a fixed pre-generated salt from python>> shell and set it in the code?

Comment: Please have a look at the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29): `In a typical usage for password authentication, the salt is stored along with the output of the one-way function, sometimes along with the number of iterations to be used in generating the output (for key stretching).`. Using the same salt for all passwords I'd say breaks its usefulness.

Comment: Indeed - using a single salt makes it significantly less useful. It means general rainbow tables are useless, but someone brute forcing could use one run for your entire DB. Using a salt for each item means they need to either brute force massive strings or do each item individually, massively increasing the work needed. Also, BCrypt stores the salt in the output hash string, I believe - so there is no need to store the salt again.

Comment: @Lattyware, I can't understand what do you are trying to say. You are saying `using a single salt makes it significantly less useful.` then again saying `I believe - so there is no need to store the salt again.`

Comment: @guru Right, so BCyrpt hashes your value with a random salt, then gives you an output string, which is the hashed value prefixed with the salt. This means that you don't need to store the salt in the database separately, as it'll be in the hash string you store. This also means there is no reason not to use a separate salt for each value, which you should do.

Comment: @Lattyware Thanks for your comments. They've been really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The format for salt is:

```
$Version$log2(NumRounds)$salt
```

where:

- `Version` is `2`,
- `0 <= log2(NumRounds) < 32`,
- `salt` is a 22-byte base-64 encoded string.

I suggest you use `bcrypt.gensalt()` instead. There's no good reason for you to provide your own salt.

Comment: own salt = calculating `bcrypt.gensalt()` from python shell then use it in python code as static salt.